# IOS How to get the event when xib file is loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I am trying to load a UItableviewcell xib file to the UITableView.
I want to know the real size of tableviewcell and change the size of subviews in xib file.
So I want to the know the name of event when the xib file is loaded.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Probably `awakefromnib` method of the cell will be called when it will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Then how can I get the running size of uitableviewcell?

Comment: `self.contentView.bounds.size()` in `awakefromnib` mehod will fetch you the size of the cell.

Comment: layoutSubViews will call after all the constraints are applied.

Comment: You can normally get the geometry of any given UIView from its frame property. This will contain a CGRect (origin and size).  Check the frame of the UITableViewCell contentView property, it should have the information that you are looking for.  You may also check the bonds instead, since frame and bounds are essentially the same, but with one in relation to its parent, and to itself.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I get the 
fwidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width.
fhegiht = self.contView.frame.size.height.
The size is that what i designed. not size when running on the iPhone.
Is there any way to get the size when it is on the device?

Comment: you can get the updated size in the layoutSubViews() delegate. From there you can rearrange the sub views.

Comment: Thanks. It works!
- (void)layoutSubviews {
fwidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width;
fheight = self.contentView.frame.size.height;
}
Solve my problem.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews { fwidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width; fheight = self.contentView.frame.size.height; }
```